# How to assgin SNI when use IP in url？

Tags: android, ssl, networking, httpurlconnection, sni

I got a single server 1.1.1.1 serving several host A.com and B.com.
So each domain got its own certificate.

When I am using host based url:

```
URL url = new URL("https://B.com/23o8PS");
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.connect();
Certificate[] certificates = ((HttpsURLConnection) conn).getServerCertificates();
System.out.println(certificates.length + " " + certificates[0].toString());
```

I can successfully get B.com's certificate. But if I use IP based url (by adding Host field to indicate the host) as below:

```
URL url = new URL("https://1.1.1.1/23o8PS");
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setRequestProperty("Host", "B.com");
conn.connect();
Certificate[] certificates = ((HttpsURLConnection) conn).getServerCertificates();
System.out.println(certificates[0].toString());
```

I just got A.com's certificate as if it is returned as a default certificate from the server. Which seems like the SNI can not be set according to the HOST HEADER field of the HttpURLConnection.

Any suggestion how I can deal with this situation?

Comment: Use the hostname in the URL. AFAIK, the whole SNI negotiation happens before any HTTP headers are transmitted.

Comment: @CommonsWare I know it happens before headers are transmitted, but SNI has to get the host information before it negotiates with the server, which I thought is from the url. So I wonder if it can obtain the host from Header field instead of url since the Header field has a higher priority. And which seems not work. So there is no way for me to do it with a IP based request?

Comment: @Ryan: I doubt that you can deal with this at the abstraction level of a HttpUrlConnection. You can do it at the level of Sockets, see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/SSLCertificateSocketFactory.html#setHostname(java.net.Socket, java.lang.String).

Answer (score 3):

[Server Name Identification (SNI)](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4366.txt) is part of the TLS handshake.  It's passed at the very beginning and is used to determine which server certificate is used.  That handshake happens before any HTTP request is sent - if it didn't, the HTTP request would be sent unencrypted.

Per RFC 4366:

> 3.1.  Server Name Indication
>
> TLS does not provide a mechanism for a client to tell a server the  name of the server it is contacting.  It may be desirable for clients  to provide this information to facilitate secure connections to  servers that host multiple 'virtual' servers at a single underlying  network address.
>
> ...
>
> **Currently, the only server names supported are DNS hostnames**; however, this does not imply any dependency of TLS on DNS, and other name types may be added in the future (by an RFC that updates this document).  TLS MAY treat provided server names as opaque data and pass the names and types to the application.
>
> "HostName" contains the fully qualified DNS hostname of the server, as understood by the client.  The hostname is represented as a byte string using UTF-8 encoding [UTF8], without a trailing dot.
>
> ...
>
> **Literal IPv4 and IPv6 addresses are not permitted in "HostName".**

You can not use IP addresses with SNI.

Which makes sense - the entire purpose of SNI is to support multiple virtual hosts on a single IP address.

Also, see [the Java JSSE documentation.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html)

Comment: Yea, it would make sense IF and only IF a machine could not have multiple private ips, such as 127.0.0.1 and 192.168.1.x, etc.  But since they can, it actually doesn't make sense. Also, one machine could have multiple network cards, in which case it would also be possible.

Comment: @StefanSteiger And all that does would be to misuse SNI to attach another label to a virtual server in a way that doesn't solve anything. If you want to connect to "virtualServerA" at IP 1.2.3.4, **you use "virtualServerA" for SNI**.  Problem solved.  Being able to add 1.2.3.5 as another label to "virtualServerA" solves nothing new and only adds confusion.

Answer (score 1):

What I want is to specify IP for the request instead of DNS.

So I have worked out another method to solve this problem.

I customized a SSLSocketFactory, overrode *createSocket* method and specified the IP address for the *SSLSocket*. This also works under **Single IP with multiple domains** scene.